# Could someone point me to an unsorted dictionary?

Tags: file, sorting, text, text-files

I am working on some sorting algorithms and need something to practice on. When searching for an unsorted dictionary file, all I get is results for people looking for help. I'm seeking a problem, not a solution.

Could someone point me to an unsorted dictionary? The bigger the better, I'm hoping to find one around 120,000 lines.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you take a sorted dictionary and shuffle it?

Comment: Have you considered randomizing one of the many sorted dictionaries you've found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On linux you can just use `shuf /usr/share/dict/words` to create your own random dictionary. On my machine this dictionary contains 98569 so not yet the size you are looking for. However if you find a larger ordered dictionary, you will be able to shuflle it with the `shuf` command as well.

Also if you need multiples of each word, you can just do `cat /usr/share/dict/words /usr/share/dict/words /usr/share/dict/words /usr/share/dict/words | shuf` and each word will be present four times.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've used is a foreign language translation dictionary, with the first column containing the sorted foreign  words stripped out.   This leaves an unsorted word list, although it is not completely random, since similar words often have similar translations.